# How to add jars to JMeter's classpath in non-GUI mode

Tags: java, classpath, jmeter, benchmarking

I have created a test plan in the JMeter GUI which uses the "Java Request Sampler".

I added the jarfile which contains the implementation to my sampler to /lib/ext/ of my jmeter installation.

This all works fine when I run it in GUI mode.

However when I switch to non gui mode using

```
./jmeter -n -t Test\ Plan.jmx
```

I get:

```
com.mycompany.JavaSamplerTest java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

2014/01/23 15:25:25 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: StandardJMeterEngine@5efbfd6e-Java Request    Exception initialising: com.mycompany.JavaSamplerTest java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.JavaSamplerTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.initClass(JavaSampler.java:117)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.testStarted(JavaSampler.java:263)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:214)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have no clue why this behaves differently when using `-n -t`. Does anybody have a solution to this?

I work on Linux using openjdk if this is somehow a helpful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the jar in jmeter/lib folder.

lib/ext is for real plugins.

Comment: Ok, thanks I did it, but it does not change anything in the behaviour.

Comment: Could you show jmeter.log content ? Are you sure there are no missing dependencies of your class ?

Comment: I will edit the exception into the question. I don't think so because it does work perfectly in GUI mode.

Comment: Check rights of your jar, are they the same as user running jmeter ?

Comment: Yeah, all the same. Do you have an idea why it works in the GUI? I have no idea how the difference can be explained.

Comment: Could you make a simple test case with a dummy Sampler and see what happens ? Would it be possible to show your code ?

Comment: Yeah, sure I will do that, thanks for your help. Unfortunately I will not have time for that before Monday.

Comment: Ok, funny: with a down stripped example it does work. However only if I put it into the lib/ext subfolder. I will have a look at the dependencies of my real sampler and check it, thanks a lot.

Comment: In my case I was not missing the jar file rather my class was not getting initialized looking at Jmeter.log helped me.

Answer (score 3):

As per [How do I run JMeter in non-gui mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) article you can use `-J` key to provide additional classpath elements location to JMeter like below:

`./jmeter -Juser.classpath=/some/folder/your/extension.jar -n -t ${path_to_your_script} -l ${path_to_results}`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that and it does not change anything in the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

### Below is how I have the plugin set-up for maven pom

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
   <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>jmeter-tests</id>
               <goals>
                   <goal>jmeter</goal>
               </goals>
               </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <testPlanLibraries>
               <artifact>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0</artifact>
           </testPlanLibraries>
           <propertiesSystem>
               <user>${username}</user>
           </propertiesSystem>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today with jmeter 5.4 on a linux machine.
Thanks to my colleague we identified the root cause.

In jmeter.properties we use the following line to extend the classpath libs.
user.classpath=../lib;../lib/ext

Howerver on a linux machine this line hast to be look like:
user.classpath=../lib:../lib/ext

Thus use : instead of ;
In our case this fits our problem.

Answer (score -2):

Add it as a dependency inside the jmeter plugin:

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>
```